# Low accuracy in K-NN model due to OneHotEncoding

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn, one-hot-encoding

I tried building a K-Nearest Neighbor model for [a dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/vertebral+column) in which the dependent variable can take 3 different categorical values.

I built 2 different models, one where I OneHotEncoded the dependent variable and one where I didn't use any encoding.

```
x_3class = class3.iloc[:,:-1].values
y_3class = class3.iloc[:,-1:].values 

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories="auto")
y_3class_ohencoded = ohe.fit_transform(y_3class).toarray() 

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#non-encoded split
x3c_train,x3c_test,y3c_train,y3c_test = train_test_split(x_3class,y_3class,test_size=0.2,random_state=1)

#onehotencoded split
x_train3,x_test3,y_train3,y_test3 = train_test_split(x_3class,y_3class_ohencoded,test_size=0.2,random_state=1)

#Feature Scaling
sc_3class = StandardScaler()
x3c_train = sc_3class.fit_transform(x3c_train)
x3c_test = sc_3class.transform(x3c_test)
sc_3class_ohe = StandardScaler()
x_train3 = sc_3class_ohe.fit_transform(x_train3)
x_test3 = sc_3class.transform(x_test3)

#Model Building 
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier 
knn_classifier_3class = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=18)
knn_classifier_ohe = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=18)

knn_classifier_3class.fit(x3c_train,y3c_train)
knn_classifier_ohe.fit(x_train3,y_train3)

#Accuracy Evaluation
nonencoded_accuracy_=cross_val_score(knn_classifier_3class,x3c_test,y3c_test,cv=10)
onehotencoded_accuracy=cross_val_score(knn_classifier_ohe,x_test3,y_test3,cv=10)

print("NonEncoded Model Accuracy: %0.2f" %(nonencoded_accuracy.mean()),"\n",
"OHEncoded Model Accuracy: %0.2f"%(onehotencoded_accuracy.mean()))
```

Accuracy score of non-encoded model was 13% higher than the OneHotEncoded model.

```
NonEncoded Model Accuracy: 0.63 
 OHEncoded Model Accuracy: 0.50
```

What would be the reason for such a big difference?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: I'm voting to reopen: the confusion here is in sklearn's interpretation of the problem depending on the input format, and so about programming more than ML theory.  (One-hot encoding the target tells sklearn that it's a multilabel problem.)

Answer (score 0):

When you one-hot encode the target, sklearn sees multiple columns and assumes you have a multilabel problem; that is, that each row can have more than one (or even no) label.

In kNN, this likely results in some points receiving no label: with `k=18` as in your case, consider a point with 8, 6, 4 nearest neighbors of classes 0,1,2 respectively. Without encoding, it gets label 0. With encoding, we have the separate kNN models in a one-vs-rest fashion. (The first label after encoding is 1 for class 0 and 0 for either of class 1 or 2, etc.) So the first model sees 8, 6+4 examples, and predicts "not class 0". Similarly the other two models predict zero, and the output is all zeros, i.e. no class was predicted.  If you do `cross_val_predict` instead, I expect you'll see this.

The default scoring for multilabel problems is also pretty harsh, but in this case it doesn't matter: your model will only ever predict no or exactly one class (erm, except maybe for ties?).